# Apache does not intercept JBOSS HTTP Error Code

Tags: apache, web, server, jboss

I have an Apache Web Server in front of a JBOSS app server. I have configured the ErrorDocument (with all the HTTP error codes) in Apache to return a fixed string of "There is an error".

Accessing the application is via the Apache Web Server, to the JBOSS app server.

However, when an error code of 404 throws from the JBOSS server, this Apache server did not catch the error and did not display the "There is an error", instead, the error page of JBOSS is served to the end user.

I have checked the log of Apache and can see the HTTP error code.

Can someone advise me what am I doing wrong or any additional config is needed?

Thanks and regards,
Jacky

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to display the custom HTTP error messages.

1. output a customized message

   ErrorDocument 403 "There is an error"
2. internally redirect to a local URL-path to handle the error

   ErrorDocument 404 /errorDocs/404.html
3. redirect to an external URL to handle the problem/error

   ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/cgi-bin/server-error.cgi

Please check if it is happening on all 404 scenarios and on all browsers.

I hope you are trying the method 1 and it is very straightforward one, scope of this directive is server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess. If the configuration file is updated as mentioned, it must work.

These could be the situations,

- ensure the text to be displayed is wrapped in quotes (") if it consists of more than one word.
- Microsoft Internet Explorer (MSIE) will by default ignore server-generated error messages when they are "too small" and substitute its own "friendly" error messages. The size threshold varies depending on the type of error, but in general, if you make your error document greater than 512 bytes, then MSIE will show the server-generated error rather than masking it.
- Although most error messages can be overridden, there are certain circumstances where the internal messages are used regardless of the setting of ErrorDocument. In particular, if a malformed request is detected, normal request processing will be immediately halted and the internal error message returned. This is necessary to guard against security problems caused by bad requests.

[Reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument)